# UML or class diagram for ruby fog gem interfacing with vsphere

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fog

I would like to have a UML diagram or a class diagram for the fog gem to better understand how it works. Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using RubyMine, it has a built in diagrammer. You can download a 30 day trial version for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used rdoc and yard. Rubymine was a good choice too. Thank you.